# Как работает checkout при несохраненных изменениях в рабочей директории?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

Допустим, я сделал какой-то коммит. И далее сделал изменения, так что `working directory is dirty`. Далее делаю `checkout` c созданием новой ветки и переходом на нее. Сделанные ранее изменения перекочуют в новую ветку, а в первоначальной сотрутся?

Comment: мне кажется, тут присутствует некоторое непонимание того, что такое «ветка» в git-е. это не набор коммитов, а *указатель* на коммит. когда к текущему коммиту добавляется новый коммит, этот *указатель* смещается, и начинает указывать уже на новосозданный коммит. причём смещается только **текущий** *указатель* (который назначается таковым при помощи команды `git checkout ветка`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> делаю checkout c созданием новой ветки и переходом на нее

Незакоммиченные изменения останутся в рабочей директории до тех пор пока вы не

- добавите их в индекс и не сделаете коммит в одну из веток
- или отмените
- или сделаете stash.

Т.е. если вы из вашей ветки `новой` ветки вернетесь в `старую` то они будут и там.

Comment: Спасибо. Немного не ясно, почему гит не требует их закомитить перед чекаутом

Comment: @voipp Потому что изменения в рабочей директории не конфликтуют с теми куда мы чекаутимся. Если бы был конфликт был то гит бы написал в консольку `error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:`

Comment: @voipp не требует потому, что это самая обычная практика: делаются правки, а затем они (целиком или частично) коммитятся во вновь созданную для этого ветку.

Comment: @anber при создании новой ветки никаких конфликтов и быть не может.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Ветка это указатель на коммит, при создании новой ветки обе ветки  априори будут указывать на один и тот же коммит.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin можно сделать чекаут на коммит из совсем другой ветки(а не только вновь созданной) и изменения из рабочей директории перенесутся если не будет конфликтов

Comment: @anber совершенно верно! именно потому в описанной ситуации (создание новой ветки) и не может быть конфликтов. они могут возникнуть при переключении на *существующую* ветку, но это «не наш случай».